# Is there any API avialable in j2me through which we can detect a metal?

Tags: java, java-me

I want to make metal detector application in j2me.Would you please help me....?

Is there any API available in j2me through which a metal can be detected through sensor.
or is there any other idea regarding the same plz rply me.I will be heighly obliged if you help me.

I am in waiting your response....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some phones do contain a magnetometer but the j2me specification as far as I know does not provide any way to access these.

Comment: Thought this was used to detect which way the Earth was pointing. Can it detect smaller objects?

Comment: A quick search online shows some which seem to work. I'm sure that you wont be finding any coins on the beach with it however :P

Answer (score 1):

I believe to detect metal we need some hardware. which I think would be working on magnetic theories. and There is no such h/w in most mobile phone to detect it.

> The simplest form of a metal detector consists of an oscillator producing an alternating current that passes through a coil producing an alternating magnetic field. If a piece of electrically conductive metal is close to the coil, eddy currents will be induced in the metal, and this produces an alternating magnetic field of its own. If another coil is used to measure the magnetic field (acting as a magnetometer), the change in the magnetic field due to the metallic object can be detected.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Metal Detector program written for J2ME available for download.

> The Metal Detector contains realistic sounds and cool animations, it’s fun and easy to use. The Metal Detector will give you and your friend’s hours of fun and laughs.

If you want to really detect metal you need real hardware.

Comment: Would you plz give me the link from where i can download the program.